# Creating an epsilon of room to prove convergence in mean

Tags: probability, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote $X_{(i)}(x)$ the $i$th closest point to $x$ (in $\ell_2$ norm) in an iid sample of size $n$ from the distribution of $X$.

Show that for any integrable function $f: \mathbb {R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$:

$$\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{i=1}\mathbb{E}\left \{ \left | f(X) - f(X_{(i)}(X)) \right |\right \} \rightarrow 0$$

as $n \rightarrow \infty$ whenever $k/n \rightarrow 0$

**What I've tried**

I'd like to apply the *Giving an epsilon of room* trick from tricki: http://www.tricki.org/article/Create_an_epsilon_of_room

I'll introduce a uniformly continuous function $f_e$ with bounded support that approximates $f$ such that:

$$\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f(X)|\} \leq \epsilon$$

This can be done since the space of integrable functions has the set of uniformly continuous functions with bounded support as a dense subsets. We will show the claim for $f_\epsilon$. By uniform continuity for each $\eta > 0$ there exists a $\nu > 0$ such that for all $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^d, \|\delta\|_2 \leq \nu$:

$$\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X + \delta)|\} \leq \eta$$

So we can show that each term in the summation goes to $0$:
$$\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X))|\} \leq  \mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X + \delta)|\} + 2 \|f_\epsilon\|_\infty \mathbb{P}(\|X - X_{(i)}(X)\| > \nu)$$

Both terms on the RHS can be made arbitrarily close to $0$.

Now we'll show that $\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X))|\}$ is close to $\mathbb{E}\{|f(X) - f(X_{(i)}(X))|\}$:

$$|\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X))|\} - \mathbb{E}\{|f(X) - f(X_{(i)}(X))|\}| \leq |\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X)) - f(X) + f(X_{(i)}(X))|\}|$$

By the reverse triangle inequality. Then an application of the triangle inequality gives:

$$\leq \mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X) - f(X)|\} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\{|f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X)) - f(X_{(i)}(X))|\}}_{(A)}$$

each of which is at most $\epsilon$ by construction.

I could use some feedback on my solution and reasoning.

EDIT: It's not clear to me that the quantity $(A)$ is at most $\epsilon$ since $X_{(i)}(X)$ does not have the same distribution as $X$ (and the condition on $f_\epsilon$ involves the distribution of $X$ not $X_{(i)}(X)$).

EDIT 2: We know that $X_{(i)}(X) \rightarrow^p X$, but without a continuity assumption on $f$, I can't say anything about the distribution of $f(X_{(i)}(X))$. In comparison, I know that $f_\epsilon(X_{(i)}(X)) = f_\epsilon(X) + o_p(1)$.

EDIT 3: Alternatively, it is sufficient for $f_\epsilon$ to converge to $f$ almost uniformly. Although convergence in L1 does not imply pointwise convergence, we can select a subsequence of $f_\epsilon$ for which we do have pointwise convergence. By Egorov's theorem, this implies almost uniform convergence.

Comment: "for any integrable function" I believe this should read, "for any function $f$ such that $f(X)$ is integrable".

Comment: This is correct, but a key part of the argument that you skipped is explaining why $\mathbb{P}(\|X - X_{(i)}(X)\| > \nu) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ whenever $i/n \to 0$. Is this something that was handled in a previous exercise? It boils down to proving a high-probability lower bound on the measure of a small ball around a sample point $X$.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalPeres , I had not originally shown this, but upon reviewing it I addressed it in another SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042589/law-of-large-numbers-for-nearest-neighbors-proof-feedback The main idea was to show that since they have the same support, this probability goes to 0 (although the answer on that question gives a more rigorous proof). I will try to show it starting from your hint.

Comment: If you link to that question (that has a complete answer) in your proof above, then the proof is fine.

Comment: I think there is a missing piece to this proof. We need some extra work to show that the second term in the final display is at most $\epsilon$. I think it is sufficient to show that the distribution of $X_{(i)}(X)$ is close to the distribution of $X$ for $n$ large enough

Comment: Alternatively, I think it's sufficient to instead construct $f_\epsilon$ such that it is close to $f$ in sup norm instead. Then the rest of the argument should go through without modification.

Comment: Although I don't think the last method is actually possible without additional assumptions

Comment: Any suggestions, @YuvalPeres ?

Comment: The tricki website is offline.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku we can find it on wayback machine https://web.archive.org/web/20210606042946/http://www.tricki.org/article/Create_an_epsilon_of_room?destination=node%2F153

Comment: I added some new ideas @YuvalPeres